# How to Pass two values to another php page using anchor tag?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pass the value of seller_id and also order_datetime to report-summary.php. But how can i do that? I tried the codes below but all i got us the error of `array to string conversion` error. Can anyone help me solve this? It would be better if you guys can show me examples of code on how to solve this. Thank you so much in advance any help will be appreciated!

```
 <div class="col-3 my-auto">
                  <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT *, SUM(purchase_price) as purchase_price FROM ordered_items 
                  INNER JOIN sellers ON ordered_items.seller_id = sellers.id 
                  WHERE MONTH(order_datetime) = MONTH(NOW()) GROUP BY ordered_items.seller_id";
                    $query = $conn->query($sql);
                    $row = $query ->fetch_assoc();
                    $id=['seller_id'];
                    $month=['order_datetime'];
                ?>


                  <a href="report-summary.php?sellerid=<?php echo $id;?>&month=<?php echo $month;?>">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="height:34px; padding-left:10px;">
                  <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> &nbsp; Export Report Summary
                  </button>
                  </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by:

```
$id=['seller_id'];
$month=['order_datetime'];
```

$id and $month are actually 2 arrays containing the strings 'seller_id' and 'order_datetime', and you're trying to print them.

If you want to access to your data collection (extracted from the query), you have to iterate your results and then access the single field.

To do this, you have to iterate your $row. So, it will be something like:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo 'id: ' . $row['seller_id'] . 'month: ' . $row['order_datetime'];
}
```

If $result has only one result, you can access to data without iterate through $row. So, it will be:

```
$id = $row['seller_id'];
$month = $row['order_datetime'];
```

Hope that this will help you!